# C# conditional $match

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have the following code in C# to $match the field:

```
var match = new BsonDocument
{
    { 
        "$match",
        new BsonDocument 
            { 
                { "Country", paramsEntity.Country },
                { "Company_ID", String.IsNullOrEmpty(paramsEntity.CompanyID) ? "$Company_ID" : paramsEntity.CompanyID },
                { "Staff_ID", String.IsNullOrEmpty(paramsEntity.StaffID) ? "$Staff_ID" : paramsEntity.StaffID }
            }
    }
};
```

It returns me nothing. But when I take out Company_ID from the $match, then it gives me result. Is something wrong in my Company_ID filtering?

Comment: Is this part of a bigger query, or are you using this as a filter with optional parts?

Comment: Yes there is something wrong. What are you actually trying to do here? Are you basically trying to determine if you have input parameters defined then pass those as conditions on the fields, or otherwise no condition for the field at all?

Comment: Ya..I am trying to determine whether there is input parameters.

Comment: Your fundamental misconception here is that you're trying to access an existing field of a document in the "right" part of your filter condition (as in `"field": "existingfield"`) which MongoDB simply doesn't support.

Comment: @dnickless Mongo actually _does_ support that using the $where operator. It's inefficient but it is supported. For example: `{ $where: "this.a < this.b" }`. [Docs here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/)

Comment: Fair point, @john. I keep forgetting about that horrible bugger. So I phrased that statement a little too strict then. Nonetheless, it holds true for any "normal" kind of query...

Comment: @dnickless Now that is true. We're using it in a single place in production (on a document initially matched by id) and I still dislike it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a better way of doing this, but you could do:

```
var query = collection.AsQueryable().Where(e => e.Country == paramsEntity.Country);
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(paramsEntity.CompanyId))
{
    query = query.Where(e => e.CompanyId == paramsEntity.CompanyId);
}
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(paramsEntity.StaffId))
{
    query = query.Where(e => e.StaffId == paramsEntity.StaffId);
}
```

It uses the IQueryable interface, and appends filters to the query, if they have been specified.

Alternatively, you could do this:

```
var filterBuilder = Builders<yourObjectType>.Filter;
var filters = new List<FilterDefinition<yourObjectType>>();
filters.Add(filterBuilder.Eq(o => o.Country, paramsEntity.Country));
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(paramsEntity.CompanyId))
{
    filters.Add(filterBuilder.Eq(o => o.CompanyId, paramsEntity.CompanyId));
}
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(paramsEntity.StaffId))
{
    filters.Add(filterBuilder.Eq(o => o.StaffId, paramsEntity.StaffId));
}
var dataCursor = collection.Find(filterBuilder.And(filters));
```

It compiles a list of conditions, and then ands them together to produce the result.

Answer (score 0):

This is my another way of doing it. Hope to share with the rest:

```
            dynamic param = new JObject();

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(paramsEntity.Country))
            {
                param.Country = paramsEntity.Country;
            }

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(paramsEntity.CompanyID))
            {
                param.Company_ID = paramsEntity.CompanyID;
            }

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(paramsEntity.StaffID))
            {
                param.Staff_ID = paramsEntity.StaffID;
            }

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(paramsEntity.BranchID))
            {
                param.Branch_ID = paramsEntity.BranchID;
            }

            var match = new BsonDocument
            {
                { "$match",
                    new BsonDocument { BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(param))
                }
            };
```